# What does 'notify' mean in g_signal_connect call?

Tags: glib, gobject

I see `notify::` prefix in `g_signal_connect` call:

```
g_signal_connect(p_obj, "notify::ice-gathering-state", G_CALLBACK(on_ice_gathering_state_changed), p_obj);
```

What does it mean? Is this prefix required?

Answer (score 3):

Since you might see this pop up in other contexts, I'll try to explain what's going on at a lower level: `notify` is the name of the signal, not a prefix.

The `notify` signal is what's known as a signal "with detail", and the `::ice-gathering-state` part is the "[detail argument](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/concepts.html#the-detail-argument)". For the [`notify` signal](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/signal.Object.notify.html), the detail is the name of the property to notify about. If you omit the detail, then you will get change notifications for all the properties on that object.

You might see other signals with details, though `notify` is by far the most common. What the detail means, depends on the signal, and you should read about it in that signal's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is required. It is not for usual signals. It is for signals that notify about property change. If you check [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c), you will see that `ice-gathering-state` is not an action signal, it is a property. Properties are usually read with `g_object_get`. But instead you can set a signal hander that will be called each time the property changes. And this is done by calling `g_signal_connect` with `notify::<property>` as the signal name.

Check [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter-cookbook/stable/actors-allocation-notify.html) on GLib site.